# Combining insert into using hardcoded and copy data from other table into the current table

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert the values of other sql table into the current table as well as insert some hardcoded values, how to archieve this through join

```
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate, ShipperID) 
VALUES ('10248', NULL, NULL, '1996-07-04', NULL)

SELECT
    CustomerID,  EmployeeID, ShipperID
FROM 
    Customers, Employees, Shippers
WHERE 
    CustomerID = '90' AND EmployeeID = '5' AND ShipperID= '3'
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

you can use `union all` to merge your first data to your `select` query.

```
 INSERT INTO 
        Orders(OrderID,CustomerID, EmployeeID,OrderDate,ShipperID) 
    SELECT '10248',NULL , NULL,'1996-07-04',NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        '10248', CustomerID, EmployeeID, '1996-07-04', ShipperID
    FROM 
        Customers,Employees, Shippers
    WHERE 
        CustomerID = '90' AND EmployeeID = '5' AND ShipperID= '3'
```

Comment: I did some modification to the code, and archive the results:
INSERT INTO 
        Orders(OrderID,CustomerID, EmployeeID,OrderDate,ShipperID) 
--  SELECT '10248',NULL , NULL,'1996-07-04',NULL
--  UNION
    SELECT
        '10248', CustomerID, EmployeeID, '1996-07-04', ShipperID
    FROM 
        Customers,Employees, Shippers
    WHERE 
        CustomerID = '90' AND EmployeeID = '5' AND ShipperID= '3'

Answer (score 0):

Since most of these values are constants in your example, do you just need

```
INSERT INTO 
    Orders(OrderID,CustomerID, EmployeeID,OrderDate,ShipperID) 
    values ('10248', '90', '5', '1996-07-04', '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the hard coded value and uses Union All with the query like.

`select Order_ID 
    from Orders
    where Order_ID = 3
    union all

    select 10248`

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO 
        Orders(OrderID,CustomerID, EmployeeID,OrderDate,ShipperID) 
    SELECT
        '10248', CustomerID, EmployeeID, '1996-07-04', ShipperID
    FROM 
        Customers,Employees, Shippers
    WHERE 
        CustomerID = '90' AND EmployeeID = '5' AND ShipperID= '3'